# .net runtime version 4.6.1586.0 is faulting in Azure

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, azure-cloud-services

I have a cloud service that contains a web and an api roles. These roles are deployed to azure. after successfully deploying the cloud service. The api works with no issues while the web role keeps faulting and then the app pool stops; then it returns http 503 error.

I looked at the event logs and this is the main error when i hit the web app which fault the .net runtime and then it stops the app pool in IIS.

The error from the event log:

```
Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 10.0.14393.0, time stamp: 0x57899b8a 
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.6.1586.0, time stamp: 0x575a1507 
Exception code: 0xc00000fd Fault offset: 0x00000000001a1bdc 
Faulting process id: 0xf50 Faulting application start time: 0x01d2422e9939a548 
Faulting application path: d:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe Faulting module path: D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll 
Report Id: 064f8bd0-5f56-4afd-a493-aa2373e392c3 
Faulting package full name:  
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Any help is appreciate it. i have trying to solve this for few days to get down to the core issue of this problem.

Note: the same cloud service runs using the same deployment build settings on my dev machine with no errors. also, the web and api both are deployed and exposed using https endpoints.

Thanks a lot..

Comment: I've got the same exact thing going on, did you fix it?  If so how?

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCoreModule/issues/167#issuecomment-352849188